# Mandrill setup Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mailchimp, mandrill

I'm trying to setup the Mandrill API to send transactional emails. To start with I just want to get a welcome email sent to new users that have just successfully signed up. Once I've completed that I should be able to figure out any other additional emails. I've already coded a few bits, but to be honest I'm not entirely sure I'm doing it right! The code doesn't currently work during testing, which is really annoying.

All the code is included below, all input is welcome :)

I have both the following gems installed.

- 'mandrill-api'
- 'mandrill_mailer'

I'm unsure where to place the following code, the documentation for the gem says mail.rb in config/initializers https://github.com/renz45/mandrill_mailer  (Look under 'Usage')

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address   => "smtp.mandrillapp.com",
    :port      => 587,
    :user_name => ENV['MANDRILL_USERNAME'],
    :password  => ENV['MANDRILL_API_KEY'],
    :domain    => 'heroku.com'
  }
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp

MandrillMailer.configure do |config|
  config.api_key = ENV['MANDRILL_API_KEY']
end
```

I won't be using Action Mailer so I guess I'll just change

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings
```

to

```
MandrillMailer::TemplateMailer.smtp_settings
```

???

I have a transactional_mailer.rb file under app/mailers

```
class TransactionalMailer < MandrillMailer::TemplateMailer
  default from: 'hello@randomemail.com'

  def welcome(user)
    mandrill_mail template: 'welcome_template',
      subject: "hello",
      to: {email: user.email, name: user.name},
      vars: {
        'USER_IDENTIFIER' => user.email,
        'LIST_COMPANY' => 'Your Company'
      },
      important: true,
      inline_css: true,
      async: true
  end
end
```

The app currently calls the method in the registration controller

```
 MandrillMailer.welcome(resource).deliver
```

Should it be

```
TransactionalMailer.welcome(@user).deliver
```

???

It's not working during testing on the local server (rails s) I'm new to coding and trying to work out why.

All help is appreciated!

Thanks :)

Comment: Are you sure your ENV variables are coming through. Also, you should check out mailcatcher for local testing. Not a must, but it has helped me out in situations like this.

Comment: Nick, can you explain what you mean by are the ENV variables are coming through. Sorry I'm relatively new to coding.

Comment: If your ENV (environment variables) are not set up correctly, your app won't be able to read your user name and password. Try firing up your rails console and type ENV['MANDRILL_USERNAME']. If nothing happens, your ENV variables are not set up properly.